How do I identify which display has my mouse cursor on wayland?
I'm trying to create a popup on the screen were my mouse cursor is located but I'm not entirely sure of how do I identify which WlOutput has the mouse cursor on it. Can anyone link me relevant pages in the docs on this topic because I browsed trough it and didn't seem to find anything related to it.
P.S. If the answer will include grabbing the mouse with WlSeat then is it normal that my Bluetooth mouse does not show up as a WlSeat?

Fun-fact: Wayland (and X) supports multiple simultaneous mouse-pointers in-use... so how do you want to determine which pointer/cursor is the one to use?

@Dai I'm expecting to get a list with multiple Wayland outputs in this case, but in my use case I expect the user to only have one cursor so ultimately this dosent really matter in my case.
